# What does promise-based async code provide that callback-based async code doesn't?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise

I'm very familiar with using callbacks in JavaScript to serialize logic in an asynchronous environment. Compared to using `async/await` in C# (and I believe this is coming to JavaScript), where you can do something like:

```
var y = await doAsynchronousNetWorkRequest();
return y;
```

I have found that promises offer very little improvement over handling asynchronous code vs callbacks.

With callback-based code, any logic that occurs after an asynchronous event gets placed in a callback:

```
(function() {
  var x = 5;
  makeAsyncRequest(function() {
    // then do something
  });
  return x;
})();
```

`x` will be returned before the `then do something` component executes. Likewise with promises:

```
 (function() {
  var x = 5;
  makeAsyncRequest()
    .then(function() {
       // then do something
     })
  return x;
})();
```

`x` will STILL be returned before the `then do something` component executes. And with respect to authoring your own library, aside from not having to include a callback parameter that is then executed at some point (i.e. it's ... slightly ... cleaner to just return a promise), as far as I can tell there is no functional difference between callback-based vs promise-based async code in the way that `async/await` does actually make a difference. (And the 'flying v' doesn't appear in code bases, but that doesn't matter).

Is there any benefit to using promises vs callback based asynchronous code that isn't immediately obvious?

Comment: promises, callbacks and `async`/`await` are just all different ways to do the same thing. No one is (functionally) "better " than the other. It's just a way to write cleaner more readable code, i.e. a massive nested chain of callbacks is worse than a promise chain and the promise chain can be made simpler using `async`s. Nothing is fundamentally changed, they essentially do the same thing in (mostly) the same way.

Comment: Uh, your examples are not equivalent. The `return x` needs to go *inside* the (promise) callback if `x` is the asynchronous result. And without promises, a `return` in an asynchronous callback does simply not work.

Comment: ah yes. the `x` in the async/await example is now `y`

Comment: `that isn't immediately obvious?`  `error handling`, `shorter stack`, `required for async / await`, and most importantly easier to understand code.